# Error in installing packages 'stringr', 'reshape2', and 'ggplot2', and 'rattle' on mac

Tags: r, macos, rattle

I am not a Mac user, but I am trying to help some students to install rattle on their Mac systems. I suggest them to follow [zhiyzuo post](https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rattle/), which is based on Yihui’s comment. But they get the following errors, although 'brew' is installed on their system:

```
* installing *source* package ‘stringr’ ...
** package ‘stringr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/stringr’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package ‘reshape2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/reshape2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reshape2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘reshape2’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘ggplot2’, ‘stringr’ are not available for package ‘rattle’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rattle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rattle’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message from the stringr installation.

Comment: @Ralf Stubner, I updated the question

Comment: Looks like they need to install `stringi` package first. Try `install.packages(c("stringi", "stringr", "reshape2", "ggplot2", "rattle"), dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: This is an odd error: R claims to install a source package, but it does not compile the contained code. Consequently it complains about the missing `stringr.so` library. I can't help any further since I am not a Mac user either.

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam How did you fix this?  I am having the same problem (Fedora/Linux) it is like other described above 'R claims to install a source package, but it does not compile the contained code. Consequently it complains about the missing stringr.so library. I '

Answer (score 0):

For me re-installing stringi did it and was able to install reshape2

If you don't have BiocManager, please install it.
`install.packages("BiocManager")` 
and then
`BiocManager::install("stringi", force=TRUE)`